# Is Mel Bernstein really a cop or a fraud?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, scarface

In the movie *Scarface"*, was "Mel Bernstein" really a narcotics detective or was he a fraud?

Comment: I'm confused as why there are 2 close votes on this question.  This question could use some more detail, but it's perfectly acceptable as is.  I think that users need to acquaint themselves with the rules of this site.  One person puts a close vote and then others who don't know any better follow suit and do the same.  That's not how this site is supposed to work

Comment: I thought about the same but included said details in the answer, hope it fits.

Comment: @OldPadawan Yes.  You did the correct thing in editing the question :)

Comment: Someone on Movie Mistakes said Mel *was* a policeman, but because he was so venal/corrupt, Tony felt he didn't deserve the title- that's what he meant by "Who says you were one?"

Answer (score 1):

It's never really said. Because of that and because of Tony's remark when he's about to kill him, one may understand he's not a cop, but a man paid by Lopez to put pressure on people. Tony has many ways to get real information about him, by crooked cops or other mobs. What *I* understand is that Tony, who doesn't care *at all* about killing anyone, thinks that if Bernstein is acting like a mob, he's to be seen as a mob. And not a cop. Then, in his point of view, he's killing a villain but not a cop. Many [sources](https://scarface.fandom.com/wiki/Mel_Bernstein) consider him to be a crooked cop.

When they met (1. [page 84](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Scarfacefinal.PDF) of the script) and when Tony kills him (2. page 102 of the script):

1.

> TONY (to the Large Man): Yeah, sure. You're... (snaps fingers trying to
> remember) ...Bernstein, right. Mel Bernstein. **Narcotics, right?**
>
> BERNSTEIN : That's right, Tony. I think we better talk. (indicates a
> quieter area)

2. 

> BERNSTEIN (rising from his chair): Hey, c'mon, what is this? **You can't shoot a cop, Tony.**
>
> TONY: **Whoever said you were one?**
> He fires.